# example of a commutative ring without zero divisor that is not an integral domain

Tags: ring-theory

I'm not sure if I understand this question.

An integral domain is a commutative ring (with unity) without zero-divisors. 
The question ask for an integral domain that is not an integral domain?

Can someone shed some understanding?

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe they mean without $1$?

Comment: Note that an integral domain is (as part of the definition) not the zero-ring.

Comment: It would have been stated if they had wanted 1.

Comment: For future reference please make the body of the Question self-contained with respect to stating the problem, not relying on the title alone to carry this burden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, you want a commutative ring without zero-divisors and without unity. So take $2\Bbb Z$ for instance